# Let $X$ be a metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point. Prove that $X$ is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am following the hint in Rudin to do this problem. The hint states: Fix $\delta > 0,$ and choose $x_1 \in X$. Having chosen $x_1,....,x_j,$ choose $x_{j+1} \in X$ if possible so that $d(x_i,x_{j+1})\geq \delta$ for $i=1,...,j.$ Show that this process must stop after a finite number of steps, and that $X$ can therefore be covered by finitely many neighborhoods of radius $\delta$. Take $\delta=1/n \ (n=1,2,....),$ and consider the centers of the corresponding neighborhoods.

If I am interpreting the hint correctly, it is telling me to construct a set of points that are all further apart from each other by $\delta$. Then I have to show that if this set is infinite, it will not have a limit point (easily done by showing that a given neighborhood of radius less than $\delta$ does not intersect any points in the set) and so this set is finite. Thus the open balls of radius $\delta$ cover the space $X$ and, finally, I can vary $\delta$ to construct a countable base for the set X which will show that the set is separable.

My problem is with intuition. $\mathbb{R}$ is separable since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This problem is telling me (I think) that if I fix $\delta=1$ and collect a finite number of points that are a distance of $1$ or greater from one another, then I can construct a finite cover of $\mathbb{R}.$ Basically I do not understand how $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered with a finite number of open sets as stated in the hint.

It would be of great help if someone could clear this up for me.

-Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that you are arguing that being separable implies that every infinite subset has a limit point, but this is not true because, as in your example, you can take $\mathbb{Z}$ as the set whose points are far away at a distance of 1.

Comment: ah so are you saying that I am applying my reasoning backwards?..so in my case not all separable spaces have infinite subsets with limit points, such as $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$. If a separable space did have limit points for all of its infinite subsets then we could cover it with a finite cover?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. If you let the subset be equal to the total set, then the your statement holds trivially. But I don't know what would happen if you impose more conditions on your space.